# Is it fine this change of variables? Integral in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

$$\iint_{R} \frac{x}{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dA$$
Where $R$ it's $\{x^2+y^2\leq 4,\ y\geq1\}$ I have changed to $x=r\cos{\theta}, y=r\sin{\theta}$. Seen the graph, we have $$\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6} \int_{0}^2 \frac{r\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta\sqrt{r^2}}r\ dr \theta= \int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6} \int_{0}^2 \cot\theta\ dr \theta$$ is it ok? [image]

Comment: Your new integration area is larger than the original one. Also, you probably meant $dr d\theta$ in your last integral, correct?

Comment: @blamocur yes, but I think I made a mistake on the limits, could yo see if they are wrong?

Comment: The limits are incorrect in polar coordinates. From your picture, you are quadrants I and II yet your angles do not match that. Also, $r=0$ is not in your integration domain, so it should not be in the limits. What is the equation of the line $y=1$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: @NinadMunshi should be $r\cos \theta =1\Rightarrow r=\sec \theta$

Comment: That is wrong, try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's obtain it formally from inequalities
$$x^2+y^2 \leqslant 4 \Leftrightarrow  0\leqslant r \leqslant 2$$
and
$$y=r\sin \theta \geqslant 1  \Leftrightarrow r  \geqslant \frac{1}{\sin \theta}$$
so for $r$ we have $\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \leqslant r \leqslant 2$. This last also give restrictions on $\theta$ i.e. we have
$$\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}}\int\limits_{\frac{1}{\sin \theta} }^{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

The integral is rather straightforward without any computation. The domain is symmetric about the line $x=0$ and the integrand is an odd function of $x$. Therefore

$$I = \iint_R \frac{x}{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy = 0$$